# What is the difference between v-html and v-text?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, ampersand

I had the following code using `v-text`:

```
<h1 v-text="content.title"></h1>
```

Output:

> Brand Name is B&amp;C

So I fixed it using `v-html` in the previous line:

```
<h1 v-html="content.title"></h1>
```

Output:

> Brand Name is B&C

My question is the following:

Why does it works using `v-html` and not `v-text`? I already read the Vue documentation but I don't clearly understand the difference.

Comment: What is the point of downgrading my question without any reasons ?

Comment: People are mean I guess... welcome to stack overflow, we got cookies and a boat load of bitterness. Here's an upvote do you dont lose faith in stack overflow :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`v-text` sets the [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of the node. `v-html` sets the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of the element. `&amp;` is an HTML entity. If you want HTML entities interpreted and replaced, you need to have them interpreted as HTML and not text.

Comment: I want to add that interpreting user's input as HTML poses a security risk

Comment: Thank you ! Interesting @German why does it poses a security risk ?

Comment: I think he referrers to XSS (Cross site scripting) (here's a read: https://www.computerweekly.com/tip/Cross-site-scripting-explained-How-to-prevent-XSS-attacks). You just need to be carefull that the data you put inside the v-html it comes from a safe place and/or is sanitised properly, so you don't open your website to execute malicious scripts :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply stated, if you know js:

- v-html == innerHTML
- v-text == innerText

Answer (score 0):

The **v-html** directive is  used to update a element’s innerHTML with our data. This is what separates it from v-text which means while **v-text** accepts string and treats it as a string it will accept string and render it into HTML.